# Incorporating custom Algorithm in SOLR-LUCENE , before Indexing?

Tags: java, php, algorithms, lucene, solr

**CURRENT FLOW:** I am using a custom algorithm(presently in php) to rank 
the MYSQL records before INDEXING it to SOLR .

**WHAT I WANT :** Is it possible implementing this 
ALGORITHM(may be in JAVA) inside LUCENE library.Is it a good way ?

**WHY I WANT TO DO THIS :** Right now ranking algorithm is taking approximately 
2 mins to rank the 10 lakhs document , than the Ranked documents are Indexed to Solr.

So idea is to incorporated this rank algorithm in LUCENE itself to save the 
Latency or time factor.

Is thier any feasible way to do this, and if their are any ,
does it  got any adverse effect ?